# My javascript doesn't work, but running it a few hours later, it works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This keeps happening to me. I will have a block of code that isn't working, for instance an `ng-repeat` or a jquery `.html` function, even though everything seems to be perfect. Then I'll go away for a few hours, come back, change *nothing*, and run the code again and magically it works. Is there a browser setting in chrome that says, "let's mess with this guy by blocking his code from working until he waits a few hours."  I'll paste some code that wasn't working... until it started working.

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller2">
<form ng-submit="submit()">
{% csrf_token %}
   Search:<input ng-model="artiste" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<table ng-repeat="artist in artists">
    <tr>
        <td> {({ artist.fields.link })} </td>
    </tr>
</table></div>

<script>
artApp.controller('mycontroller2', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http){
        $scope.submit = function(){
        var call = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/rest/',
            data: {
                "artiste": $scope.artiste
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFTOKEN': "{{ csrf_token }}"
            }
        };
        $http(call)
            .success(function(data){
                var response = angular.fromJson(data);
                $scope.artists = response;
            })
        }
    }]);</script>
```

This code was not updating the dom at all; I went out for 2 hours, and now it works like a charm. I swear I changed nothing. Anyone ever heard of this problem?

Comment: Could be your JS is being cached so updates that fix the code aren't being applied when you reload. Check with a hard reload (ctrl+ f5)

Comment: Your server may be sending the files to your browser with headers that tell the browser it can *cache* your JavaScript code. If you make changes, the browser may be ignoring them because it thinks it's already got an up-to-date copy of the code.

Comment: By the way, I suggest you to always add a `.error()` method, you don't know what can run wrong.

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what exactly didn't work?  Syntax error?  Server error?  $http error?

Comment: rename your js file by adding ?version at the end. The most possible solution is that you have some kind of caching and if you want to have good user experience on website, this is way to go. If you are just developing(for now) then you could just clear your cache

Comment: It would fail at the `ng-repeat` phase. The `$scope.artists` variable was getting the data that I wanted. I could see that by setting a breakpoint in "sources" in devtools. For some reason the `ng-repeat` was not getting the data, or having some problem with the data.

Comment: So have you looked in the browser console log? Control-Shift-J or F12.  Anything interesting printing in there?

Comment: The error that displays on the console with the now-working code is `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`